# How Do I Use The Variable "i" As Part Of A String in a For Loop in Java

Tags: java, string, for-loop

basically I want to do this in java

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
     System.out.println("Hello, I am "i" years old");
     }
```

So the for loop would print out

```
Hello, I am 1 years old
Hello, I am 2 years old
Hello, I am 3 years old
...
```

And so on.  How do I do this?

Comment: System.out.println("Hello, I am " + i + " years old");

Comment: Since no one has bothered to explain, `+` in Java has another function other than addition. This function is String concatenation (putting Strings together into one String)

Comment: The Java Tutorial is a nice place to start with questions like this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
 System.out.println("Hello, I am " + i + " years old");
}
```